# in the given code i want to ask that i specified "s" as char and then in scanf how it runs without &s (also runs with & and also without &)

Tags: c, scanf

how can char specified as `s` run without `&s` in `scanf` (also run with `&` and also without `&`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    printf("%c\n", ch);
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    char st[100];
    scanf("\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", st);
    printf("%s",st);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays automatically decay to a pointer to the first element when used as function arguments.

Comment: Because `s` is an array, so when passed as an argument to a function, it's equivalent to passing `&s[0]`.  So it is, in fact, passing an address.